# Putting the legend inside the graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am trying to plot a stacked barchart of the global terorrism dataset available at the following link: https://www.kaggle.com/START-UMD/gtd
My aim is to put the legend inside the graph, precisely in the bottom right, and to increase the total size of the plot in order to make it readable. The closest thing to my intention that I managed to reach get is the made up by the following code.

Library necessary for this plot

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot)
```

Code:

```
terrorism %>% 
  group_by(weaptype1_txt, weapsubtype1_txt) %>% 
  summarise(nweapons = length(weaptype1_txt)) %>% 
  ungroup() -> dfw2

ggplot(data = dfw2, aes(x = reorder(weaptype1_txt,nweapons), y = nweapons, fill = weapsubtype1_txt)) +  
  geom_bar(aes(fill=weapsubtype1_txt), stat="identity", colour="white") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw(base_size = 8)  +
   labs(title="Weapons type/subtype (1)", x ="Type of weapon used", y = "Number of events", fill = "Sub-type") + 
  theme(legend.position=c(0.8, 0.2))+
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 3), 
               legend.text = element_text(size = 3))
```

[image]

My intention is of course to not cover bars with the legend. Thank you very much for reading and, I hope, for the help.

Comment: This seems unlikely to work given how many factors are in the legend. Can you consolidate them somehow?

Comment: To second what @cardinal40 says, most data viz folks will caution against using more than a handful of colors for categories, and standard palettes like the ColorBrewer and CartoColor systems won't go past 12 at most. Some people will argue that beyond 6 colors, categories become hard to distinguish and there's probably a better way to aggregate and/or display the data. As far as the code, you can also adjust `legend.justification` in the theme

Comment: Have you got any other solution for a better graph to display?

Comment: It depends on your purpose in making a chart. I'm not sure what all is in the data or what categories might be important without downloading the whole file (`dput` of a sample would be helpful to post), but you might collapse those categories into larger clusters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you been considered to change of plot?

I suggest you a sankey diagram with `networkD3`.[image]

that is done in this way:

```
## maybe you must install some of packages first:
library(tidyverse)
library(viridis)
library(patchwork)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(circlize)
library(networkD3)

# filling no data columns wit "No Data"
dfw2$weapsubtype1_txt[dfw2$weapsubtype1_txt==""] <- "No Data"

#generating nodes (the unique type or subtype of weapon
nodes <- data.frame(name=unique(c(dfw2$weaptype1_txt, dfw2$weapsubtype1_txt)))

# correspondences are marked by number
dfw2$IDsource=match(dfw2$weaptype1_txt, nodes$name)-1 
dfw2$IDtarget=match(dfw2$weapsubtype1_txt, nodes$name)-1


# Make the Network
  san<- sankeyNetwork(Links = dfw2, Nodes = nodes,
                    Source = "IDsource", Target = "IDtarget",
                    Value = "nweapons", NodeID = "name",
                    sinksRight=FALSE,fontFamily="Source Sans Pro")
san
```

Comment: Wow that's a really cool plot! Thank you very much. I was wondering if there is a way to increase the total dimension of the output because in my html the keys and the colors are just so small.

Comment: `san<- sankeyNetwork(Links = dfw2, Nodes = nodes,
                    Source = "IDsource", Target = "IDtarget",
                    Value = "nweapons", NodeID = "name",
                    sinksRight=FALSE,fontFamily="Source Sans Pro",
                    fontSize=12)`